# What's the best way to write an SQL query for updating previously chosen interests?

Tags: php, mysql

Need help in creating a MySQL query to update multiple choices by a user or other suggestions

I have a page where users can select 3 to 6 interests by clicking on dynamically generated buttons. I've been able successfully inserted the chosen interests into the database, but I'm trying to prepare for a scenario where users might want to update their previous choices. Any suggestions on how to write my SQL query or go about users updating their previously chosen interests?
The interests are queried from the Interest table with columns: id - name - description - navigation - seo_name and the selected interests are inserted into member_interests table with columns: interest_id - member_id . I was able to solve it be deleting the previously chosen interests and creating new ones. But I don't feel comfortable with this route.

```
public function getAll(): array
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, description, navigation, seo_name 
      FROM interest;";                                 // SQL to get all interest
    return $this->db->runSQL($sql)->fetchAll();      // Return all interest
}


public function create(int $interestId, int $memberId): bool
{
     $sql    = "INSERT INTO member_interests (interest_id, member_id) 
                VALUES (:interest_id, :member_id);";            // SQL
     $params = array('interest_id' => $interestId, 'member_id' => $memberId);
    $this->db->runSQL($sql, $params);                        // Run SQL
    return true;                                           // Return true
}

public function deleteByMember(int $memberId): void
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM member_interests WHERE member_id = :member_id";
        $params = [
            'member_id' => $memberId
        ];
        $this->db->runSQL($sql, $params);
    }

..{
    $checkedCount = count($interestsChosen);
    if ($checkedCount < 3 || $checkedCount > 6) {
      $errors['message'] = 'Please select 3-6 interests.';                  // If the number of selected interests is less than 3 or more than 6, set the error message to 'Please select 3-6 interests.'
    } else {
      // Check if the user has previously chosen interests
      $previousInterests = $cms->getInterest()->getInterestName($cms->getSession()->id);
      $previousInterestIds = array_column($previousInterests, 'interest_id');

      if (count($previousInterestIds) > 6) {
        $errors['message'] = 'You can only choose up to 6 interests.'; // Set error message if user has already chosen interests and the total exceeds 6
      } else {
        // Delete existing interests for the user
        $cms->getInterest()->deleteByMember($cms->getSession()->id);

        // Iterate over the chosen interests and create them
        foreach ($interestsChosen as $interestId) {
          $cms->getInterest()->create(intval($interestId), $cms->getSession()->id);
        }

        if ($previousInterestIds) {
          // User had previously chosen interests, redirect to interests updated page
          redirect('interest-updated/', ['success' => 'Interests updated!']);
        } else {
          // User didn't have previously chosen interests, redirect to the next step in the onboarding process
          redirect('onboard-occupation/');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to compare what was checked and what is already existing and accordingly : remove the entries already existing and not checked, add the checked ones that don't exist and do nothing for what was existing and is still checked. As far as I know, you can't do it in one go, you have to implement some logic in PHP first

Comment: Look into [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/). Make `interest_id, member_id` unique in your database. Then, when the user with some a id changes one of his interest_id's, the row will be overwritten.

Comment: @Michel I don't think there's anything to overwrite, the table is just pairs of interest ID and member ID. You either add or remove interests, as Cid said.

Comment: @Cid How do the comparison & go about the logic? I want something better
      $previousInterests = $cms->getInterest()->getInterestName($cms->getSession()->id);
      $previousInterestIds = array_column($previousInterests, 'interest_id');

      if (count($previousInterestIds) > 6) {
        $errors['message'] = 'You can only choose up to 6 interests.'; 
      } else {
        $cms->getInterest()->deleteByMember($cms->getSession()->id);

        foreach ($interestsChosen as $interestId) {
          $cms->getInterest()->create(intval($interestId), $cms->getSession()->id);
        }

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar table and to simplify the code I delete all current user values and add all the new values.

Fair warnings with this approach:

1. This is not necessarily the most performant way to do this but it saves you reading and comparing existing values so it pushes the burden from the code to the database. If you do not update this list often and the list is small as appears to be true for your scenario the performance impact is minimal and the reduced code burden is well worth it.
2. This has the potential to lose data if the server is stopped or a failure occurs between the delete and write. In my scenario this risk is acceptable and that appears to be true in yours as well.

You can slightly decrease the db impact by doing all inserts in a single command.

SQL

```
DELETE FROM user_interests where user_id = :user_id
```

```
INSERT INTO user_interests SET (user_id, interest_id) VALUES (:user_id, :interest_id1);
INSERT INTO user_interests SET (user_id, interest_id) VALUES (:user_id, :interest_id2);
INSERT INTO user_interests SET (user_id, interest_id) VALUES (:user_id, :interest_id3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. I have a code that does the job by deleting all the current interests and creating new interests, already. I was holding out for a better approach.